# How to get the values in gridview row, in which the radio button is selected using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the gridview control, if the use selects a row using the radio button control in a row, On the selected index change i want to get the all the values in the row using c#.

How?

Comment: Is this for ASP.NET web forms, WPF or Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CheckChanged event of the radio button, use NamingContainer property of the sender object. That will give you the current GridViewRow. You can use that to get the other values.

Comment: I don't have one ready. But if you take a look at the sender object's NamingContainer property in QuickWatch, you will understand things.